# XML-to-JSON: what is a base element? and what is property?

Tags: xml, json

I'm trying to figure out what the author means by "base element:"

"XML elements become properties of their base element. Suppose you had the following
XML:"

```
<customer>
    <first>Bill</first>
    <last>Burke</last>
</customer>
```

The JSON mapping would look like:

```
{ "customer" :
    { "first" : { "$" : "Bill"},
       "last" : { "$" : "Burke" }
    }
}
```

I understand what's happening, but what does this person mean by base element?  Actually, what does this whole sentence mean? "XML elements become properties of their base element."  And what is a "property"  is this json property or xml property?  for xml there's elements, attributes, and values, and for json there's key and value.  So what is this "property" thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite it a bit more clearly and verbosely, "XML elements become JSON properties of the object that is the JSON representation of the parent of the XML element."

Property, in JS or JSON, is the key-value pair on an object, the rough equivalent of an attribute in XML (pairs of names and values on tags).

In your specific case, the XML element `<first>` becomes the property `first` on the object that is the value of `customer`, which represents the `<customer>` tag (which is a parent, or a base tag, of `<first>`).

Comment: just to confirm my understanding:  a json property is a combination of both key and value.  Then what is a "base element?"  Is it the root element or the sub element?

Comment: I understand it.  base equals root.  author should have defined the vocabs first.

Comment: Shouldn't be root, should be parent; it's irrelevant of course in this particular situation, but it would be obvious on a deeper nesting. Basically, you're overthinking it - XML and JSON are structurally equivalent, except that XML has both attributes (for string values) and child nodes (for anything), while JSON has only properties that can hold anything: strings, objects or arrays. The rest is just syntax.

Comment: @Amadan Not really. XML elements can have multiple children with the same tagName, whereas JSON objects cannot have multiple properties with the same key.

Comment: @torazaburo: Yes. This is normally translated into JSON using an array value. "equivalent" should have been "more or less equivalent". My point was simply that translation from XML to JSON is usually a rather simple affair (if you just ignore namespaces; let's not go there).